# Why is it so difficult for new users on Area 51 to understand the Area 51 phases?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, definition-phase

I have launched a proposal on Area 51, and I was super enthusiatic, but I am now realizing that Area 51 is surprisingly terrible at "educating" new users.

For the first phase (definition), I would expect some "helper messages" for a user who has less than, let's say, 100 points. So that he understands there is no need to "reply" to questions, but only to vote questions up/down and post questions he'd like to see on the forum proposed.

In my case, I end up having to contact people directly (via email or [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) or else...*sigh...*), or [write such "fake" discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13069) to explain them the Area 51 proposal phases. Many times, users were enthusiastic and happy to contribute after I explained them (only) how the definition phase work. I did mention the FAQ before, but only some users would read it, maybe because it's unclear, badly formatted, too intimidating, or too long (users who are at work don't have/take time to read such a long page).

I suspect these problems could be coming from the lack of a dedicated meta for Area 51. I'm not even sure to post my question on the correct meta site right now!

EDIT: just two hours after posting the "fake question" to educate the new users, our questions jumped from 17 to 23 questions! The response is even better than I hoped really and show that users are happy to participate, but just need to be pointed in the right direction more clearly.

Comment: You might need this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I know this, as far as I've experienced, most new users/followers don't read it. It might just be too much info. In the end, new users only need to know the very minimum (what the definition phase is abt, a link towards a page with more info, that's it)

Comment: Well, they should..the FAQ section has been well written. I would love to make a video tutorial, if the mods are okay with it.

Comment: People who won't read an FAQ aren't going to participate in a meta site.

Comment: This is a bold statement. I am only asking for improvement to encourage users to participate. The FAQ is not very friendly, SE is usually very good with user-friendlyness, pointing them in the right direction. This is not the case on Area51, that's all.

Comment: I edited my question to try to explain my point better. I really wished the FAQ was good enough to explain users how things work. But it does not seem to suit what they're expecting.